# Can serialize, but cannot deserialize?

Tags: c#, serialization, poco, t4

I've created POCO classes with T4 Templates for EF 4.0 and generated mock for Context. Everything was great, but i don't like to initialize even small Mock-DB in C# code, so i've created some functions which generates Mock-DB from real DB and i wanted to serialize this object and use it later in some Unit Tests...

XML serialization fails, so i've tried binary serialization and serialization succeed, but deserialization failed.

Deserializer cannot find assembly "EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-". How can i deserialize such thing (DynamicProxy?)...

Comment: Is the serializer in a seperate assembly?

Comment: You mean different than this with POCO classes? Serializer is in TestProject and Poco classes and generated mocks are in separate project with models only, so yes they are in separate assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic proxies only exist on-demand, so are poor choices for serialisation. What us the error with XML? Ultimately I expect your best option here is to use a DTO layer, but that *might* also serialize with some other serializers. For example have you tried DataConttactSerializer, which may be able to cope? I've been adding proxy support to my own serializer but I haven't tried with ef4 yet.

Comment: I don't know, is it worth my effort.I just want to create small part of big DB, which can be used easily in Unit Testing. It should be static, so i thought serializing would be the best and the fastest way.I haven't tried DataContractSerializer, but i'm thinking also about other possiblility... Is there any way to get real object from proxy object? What am i doing right now is traversing through DB, starting point is one entity, and i'm fetching all dependencies adding them to MockContext (which is based on List<>),so mayby during adding object to MockContext i could skip proxy.Is it possible?

Comment: While serializing via XML, i got XmlInclude errors. Serializer find unexpected type and i should add XmlInclude to types which aren't known statically...

Comment: @Simon - yes, that is what I *expected*, but wanted to be sure. I don't know enough about the EF implementation to know about that, but that *is* possible with NHibernate, I expect it is possible. But you'd have to google it. DTO is simpler...

Comment: I know NHibernate is capable of such things :) But i have to deal with EF 4.0, unfortunately. I don't think DTO is better and i wanted to avoid it. I've tried to google it, but it's not as easy :)

Comment: @Simon - try `ProxyDataContractResolver` + `DataContractSerializer`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx

Comment: I'm not familiar with WCF. I've added attributes to my interface (Context and MockContext both inherit from this interface) but when i'm serializing via BinaryFormatter i got serialized Proxies, and XmlSerializer still have troubles - no reflecting type error, cannot serialize ICollection[<...>]. How can i make use of those attibutes during serialization?

Answer (score 1):

If you create your instance of the class first from the entity context in the app the deserializes it, it may work for you. So in your application that is to deserialize this, attempt to do something like

context.YourSerializedObjectType.CreateObject();
where context is an instance of your entity object context.

I had a similar issue I was able to work around (partly) by doing this in an mvc web app's Application_Start

http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/09/aspnetmvcentity-framework-error-unable.html

give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful able to solve this by registering a custom SerializationBinder with the BinaryFormatter: (EF6)

```
string file = "data.bin";
using (var ctx = new DataContext())
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Binder = new MyBinder();

    Entity e;
    using (var s = File.OpenRead(file))
        e = (Entity)bf.Deserialize(s);

    ctx.Entities.Add(e);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    File.Move(file, Path.Combine(archiveFolder, Path.GetFileName(file)));
}



class MyBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    Dictionary<string, Type> types;

    public MyBinder()
    {
        types = typeof(Entity).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace == "Foo.Model").ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t);
    }

    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (assemblyName.Contains("EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Foo"))
        {
            var type = typeName.Split('.').Last().Split('_').First();
            return types[type];
        }

        var returnType = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName));
        return returnType;
    }
}
```